# Difference between choosing last pivot vs first pivot in hoare's partition

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, sorting, java-8

I have been trying to figure out the differences in implementation of hoare's partition when the pivot is first element and when pivot is last element.I have put down the observations made by me below, I am not sure of the following though.

**Last element as pivot**

```
partition(arr[], lo, hi)
{
pivot = arr[hi]
i = lo   // Initialize left index
j = hi   // Initialize right index
while(true) 
  {
  while (arr[i] < pivot) 
  i++;

  while (arr[j] > pivot)
  j--;

  if i >= j
  return i; // line z

  swap(arr[i],arr[j]);
  i++;
  j--;    
  }
}
```

and while doing quicksort, the function call to partition will look like below

```
quicksort(int[] arr,int low,int high)
{
if(low<high)
 {
 int pivot=partition(arr,low,high);
 quicksort(arr, low, pivot-1); // line x
 quicksort(arr, pivot, high);  // line y
 }
}
```

**First element as pivot**

```
partition(arr[], lo, hi)
{
pivot = arr[lo]
i = lo   // Initialize left index
j = hi   // Initialize right index
while(true) 
  {
  while (arr[i] < pivot) 
  i++;

  while (arr[j] > pivot)
  j--;

  if i >= j
  return j; //line z

  swap(arr[i],arr[j]);
  i++;
  j--;    
  }
}
```

and while doing quicksort, the function call to partition will look like below

```
quicksort(int[] arr,int low,int high)
{
if(low<high)
 {
 int pivot=partition(arr,low,high);
 quicksort(arr, low, pivot); // line x
 quicksort(arr, pivot+1, high);  //line y
 }
}
```

The observations I have made are line x, y and z of both codes are different. Are these right, or would I get any fail of testcases if I use any of these algo for quicksort? Any help would be appreciated, Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hoare partition scheme can use any element for the pivot. Using the middle element is common.

Comment: but the middle element is either swapped with the last or first element before going ahead with the partition. I just want to know if the implementation and differences in these two ways seen by me are valid.

Comment: For Hoare partition scheme, the pivot not initially swapped, or swapped just before the end of a partition step. Instead it gets swapped (if needed) in the interim steps during the swaps of values < pivot or values > pivot.